# Silverstripe user defined forms files uploaded by user getting published

Tags: forms, content-management-system, silverstripe

In my Silverstripe 4 website I have a user defined form with a file upload field.

If a user uploads any files, those are getting published directly. So those files are getting crawled in search results.

Is there any way so that files uploaded by users won't get published? Just go as a draft files?

or

I don't need to save those files in CMS?

Any options to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using a Silverstripe 3 or Silverstripe CMS 4 ? Things may have changed betweent this versions. And can you please check which version of UserForms you're using in this project? Composer might tell you the version number.

Comment: Silver stripe 4. And don't know User-forms version. I am a tester. All I have access to is CMS. Cant check this. Developers are trying to resolve this. But I just posted to check if anyone has solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

In Silverstripe 4 what we can do is create a directory to upload to and set the directory so that only logged in users can view the files in there. This way the files uploaded through the form will not be accessible by web crawlers or the general public.

1. Go to the Files section in the CMS `/admin/assets/`.
2. Create a directory for the form uploads (e.g. `applications`)
3. Set the permissions of the `applications` directory of `Who can view this file?` to `Logged-in users`

[image: Set the permissions of the applications directory of Who can view this file?: to Logged-in users]

4. Edit your user defined form page's file upload field
5. Set `Select upload folder` to `applications`

[image: Set Select upload folder to applications]

6. Save and publish

Now user's will be able to submit the form and upload files, but only logged in users will be able to view the uploaded files.

Comment: thanks I had done the same. But it was not working with some specific folder. But When I created a new folder and followed above steps. It worked. :)